# Modal view won't dismiss

Tags: iphone, ios, modalviewcontroller

I found many similar questions, but couldn't find solution to my problem anyway.
So, my app (it consists of tabView) needs to download data from server after the first start. To perform this it calls modal viewcontroller where it checks for internet connection using Reachability.h/m and NSNotification defaultCenter. If internet is reachable the download is started and data is saved. When accomplished I want to close modaly opened viewcontroller, but it is reloading over and over again. I'm stick with this almost 2 days, please help :)

This is part of my code: in first ViewController

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    //checking for data if not calls modalViewController
    if(firstStart){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"startDownload" sender:self];
    }

}
```

In second(modal ViewController)

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
    // check for internet connection
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

     internetReachable = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
     [internetReachable startNotifier];

     // check if a pathway to a random host exists
     hostReachable = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"www.apple.com"];
     [hostReachable startNotifier];  

}
```

in checkNetworkStatus is done check for internet connection if internet connection is present is performed JSON download and parsing and in the end is called Close method

```
-(void)Close
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

After this call the screen goes to first ViewController and immediately changes to second and all the stuff is performed again, it is kind of stucked in the cycle.

Comment: Probably firststart is always true. How do you set firststart?

Comment: what do you meant by saying firststart?

Comment: I have made sipler project just to test. 2 viewcontorllers 1-st is calling second by segue in viewdidappear. 2-nd is closed from his viewdidappear  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; - I have exactly the same situation,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the first view controller's `viewDidAppear` is called not only when it first appears, but also when the second view controller's modal is dismissed and the first view reappears. And `viewDidAppear` checking some variable, `firstStart`, but clearly this `firstStart` variable is not is not getting reset properly between the initial `viewDidAppear` of the first controller, and the second `viewDidAppear` of the first controller.

You either need to have the second controller update the value of this `firstStart` variable (e.g. via a delegate protocol) somehow, or recalculate the `firstStart` when the first view reappears.

Comment: actualy first start is array which is populated from file, file is created in second viewcontroller (after JSON download and parsing) so after first call of secondviewcontroller the file is created and it is similar to what you have written, but anyway thanks!

Comment: Ok let's make things even more simpler, instead of calling performSegueWithIdentifier I'm opening secondview from appdelegate

Comment: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //after reading from file
    if(!self.largeStickerFileNames)
    {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        JSONDownloadViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"downloadView"];
        [(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    }
    return YES;
}

Comment: and still couldn't dismiss from 2nd view

Comment: @DavidGeghamyan let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24662/discussion-between-rob-and-david-geghamyan)

Comment: Thank you guys! And special thanks to Rob! As I moved the check for performing segue from viewdidload to viewdidappear it starts to work.